# Passing a value from calculator frame to text field

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe, calculator, internal

I have an internal JFrame of a calculator. 
I need to compute a value on the calculator and when I click on the TOTAL button from the same class (not inside the JFrame), it should display the same value onto the text field for TOTAL. How can I do that? I use Java eclipse.

> my button calculator code:

```
btnCalc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            Calculator frame = new Calculator();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setBounds(555, 70, 395, 260);
            getContentPane().add(frame);
        }
    });
```

Putting number into the text field calculator:

```
twoText = textField.getText() + two.getText();
```

Comment: add some code to see how are you relating them

Comment: Convert the total value to a String, and use the setText method of the text field to write the total String to the text field.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc but how do I take the value from another internal JFrame?

Comment: Show your code in your question, not in a comment, and you get the answer.  Ask a question with no code, and you get an answer with no code.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc updated

Comment: It's just a guess, since you provided limited code, but textfield.setText(twoText)?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]